# R igraph contract vertex character attributes

Tags: r, igraph

I'm using in Visual Studio R Tools (CRAN R 3.3.2) igraph 1.0.0 contract function to merge some vertices in a graph using `vertex.attr.comb = "first"`.
It works ok for numeric attributes but for character attributes the attribute is changed to a list. One of the attributes is shape.
After contract `tkplot` fails, because `V(g)$shape` is a list.

I have a graph g with attributes:

```
data.frame(a = vertex_attr_names(g), b = unlist(lapply(vertex_attr_names(g), function(x) mode(vertex_attr(g, x, V(g))))))
                   a         b
1             Period character
2       Organization character
3     EmplPermanence character
4           EmplType character
5       FullParttime character
6  JobClassification character
7             Gender character
8                Age character
9          Education character
10    PersonnelCount   numeric
11            source character
12             index   numeric
13        graphlevel   numeric
14              kind character
15              name character
16             value   numeric
17             layer   numeric
18             color character
19              type   logical
20            status character
21               aka character
22         completed   logical
23            branch   numeric
24        branchname character
25             shape character
26              size   numeric
```

I use

```
test <- contract(g, NewVertices, "first")
```

and look at the attributes:

```
data.frame(a = vertex_attr_names(test), b = unlist(lapply(vertex_attr_names(test), function(x) mode(vertex_attr(test, x, V(test))))))
                   a       b
1             Period    list
2       Organization    list
3     EmplPermanence    list
4           EmplType    list
5       FullParttime    list
6  JobClassification    list
7             Gender    list
8                Age    list
9          Education    list
10    PersonnelCount numeric
11            source    list
12             index numeric
13        graphlevel numeric
14              kind    list
15              name    list
16             value numeric
17             layer numeric
18             color    list
19              type    list
20            status    list
21               aka    list
22         completed    list
23            branch numeric
24        branchname    list
25             shape    list
26              size numeric
27             round numeric
```

When I try to use tkplot on test:

```
lbl <- vertex_attr(test, "index", V(test))
lbl <- unlist(lbl)
> tkplot(test, layout = coord, vertex.label = lbl,
+             vertex.label.family = "sans", vertex.label.cex = 0.8,
+             edge.width = 2, edge.arrow.size = 0.5, edge.arrow.width = 0.5)
Error in as.tclObj(x, drop = TRUE) : cannot handle object of mode 'list'
```

I haven't found my way around this yet. Can anybody help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question does not contain a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4303162). It is therefore hard to understand your problem and give you an appropriate answer. Please make your data available (e.g. by using `dput()`) or use one of the example data sets in R. Also, add the minimal code required to reproduce your problem to your post.

Comment: Thank you, @Stibu! As you can see, I'm a newbie in stackoverflow. Of course I should've studied the problem a bit more, tried at least one other scenario. I didn't then, but now I did. And I cannot reproduce the problem. I'll get back to this if it turns out again. But for now I'd consider this solved.